# jquery - strange behavior in IE

Tags: jquery

** Rephrased **

**Fails on Load in IE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">            
            $(document).ready(function(){                
                $(document).find('form').attr('id', 'FRM_0');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>jQuery Dynamic Form</h1>
        <form id="testForm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the jquery code you are using? I don't see any javascript here.

Comment: jQuery selectors work with id or class attributes, not name attributes? Should you not be using `<input type="hidden" id="someId"/>`??

Comment: I included the javascript now.. I am using dynamicforms.http://sroucheray.org/blog/demos/jquery-dynamic-form/

Comment: I'm still puzzled. The js doesn't tell me much. You really should have an id or class name on form fields though.

Comment: Just a moment please I will work the sample code and post it. The production one is too big to include here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails'? Script error? jQuery selector returns an empty set? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is a script error..

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 998
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: jquery-dynamic-form/lib/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js

Comment: @stackoverflow, KP is right -- without more details as to how it fails (or else the contents of `#formRow` to work with -- both would be the best) we can't really help.

Comment: Please check now. I have rephrased with a sample code.

Comment: Chrome does not complain

Comment: @stackoverflow -- much better; you've left out the `jquery-dynamic-forms.js` bit that you were working on before though.  Where would that go in your example?

Comment: That would not be required.. The error occurs not in dynamic forms but here: $(document).find('form').attr('id', 'FRM_0');

Comment: Is this a bug in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in jQuery. The only resolution I found so far is by changing 'id' to someother value. Create a ticket http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6336.

Comment: Message from JQuery: **Don't give your form elements the same names as standard form properties (id, name, action, method, etc.)**

Useful link: http://yura.thinkweb2.com/domlint/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for posting the answer here stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=hidden][name=id]');
```

Should get you exactly what you want, and it should work in IE. (If I could see the Javascript code you are using, I might be able to be more helpful.)